# Area Under the Curve in triplicate Python

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I conducted an experiment in triplicate (so each wavelength has 3 corresponding values). I need to get the total area under the curve (one value) for each wavelength. How would I go about doing this in python using pandas?

Comment: Without more information answering this question will be difficult. I would recommend taking a look at [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) documents. Try as best as possible to show what you would like to do, what you have done, and what you would like the result to be